# Time differences in hours and minutes via Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

[image]

I would like to calculate the time differences between 2 times using moment.js

I've been using JS to archive it.

```
function timeDiffCalc(dateFuture, dateNow) {
    let diffInMilliSeconds = Math.abs(dateFuture - dateNow) / 1000;

    // console.log(dateFuture,dateNow);

    const days = Math.floor(diffInMilliSeconds / 86400);
    diffInMilliSeconds -= days * 86400;
    // console.log('calculated days', days);

    const hours = Math.floor(diffInMilliSeconds / 3600) % 24;
    diffInMilliSeconds -= hours * 3600;
    // console.log('calculated hours', hours);

    const minutes = Math.floor(diffInMilliSeconds / 60) % 60;
    diffInMilliSeconds -= minutes * 60;
    // console.log('minutes', minutes);

    let difference = '';
    if (days > 0) {
        difference += (days === 1) ? `${days} day, ` : `${days} days, `;
    }

    difference += (hours === 0 || hours === 1) ? `${hours} hour, ` : `${hours} hours, `;

    difference += (minutes === 0 || hours === 1) ? `${minutes} minutes` : `${minutes} minutes`; 

    return difference;
}
```

---

**Curent Codes**

```
var CurrentDate    = new Date();
var nextFeedString = '2021-03-22 18:27:08';
nextFeedString     = nextFeedString.replace(' ', 'T');
var timeLeft       = timeDiffCalc(new Date(nextFeedString), new Date());
```

It works as the image above, but I'm seeking a better/shorter way of doing it via moment.js.

**New Codes**

```
var startTime      = moment(new Date(), "HH:mm:ss a");
var endTime        = moment(nextFeedString, "HH:mm:ss a");
var duration       = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
var hours          = parseInt(duration.asHours());
var minutes        = parseInt(duration.asMinutes())%60;
var timeLeft       = hours + ' hour and '+ minutes+' minutes.'; <<< it seems worse than what I got
```

Is there a better function of moment.js that I should use?

## Edit

```
function timeLeftFromNow(endTime) {

    var nowTime        = moment(new Date(), "HH:mm:ss a");
    var endTime        = moment(endTime, "HH:mm:ss a");
    var duration       = moment.duration(endTime.diff(nowTime));
    var hours          = parseInt(duration.asHours());
    var minutes        = parseInt(duration.asMinutes())%60;
    var timeLeft       = `${hours} hour${hours > 1 && "s"} and ${minutes} minute${minutes > 1 && "s"}`;


    return timeLeft; 

}

var nextFeedString = '{{ $nextFeed }}';
nextFeedString     = nextFeedString.replace(' ', 'T');
var timeLeft       = timeLeftFromNow(nextFeedString);
```

I got

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your moment code is the way to do it,

you could replace your last line by :

```
const timeLeft = `${hours} hour${hours > 1 ? "s" : ""} and ${minutes} minute${minutes > 1 ? "s" : ""}.`
```

And replace all your vars by const to be more ES6 friendly !

Comment: I tried your code, and the result contains the word "false" in there.

Comment: It's ok. It works now. Thanks. You seems know a lot about time related codes. Do I still need to do this ? `nextFeedString     = nextFeedString.replace(' ', 'T');` for it to work in Safari ?

Comment: No you shouldn't need to do this, did you try your code on safari ?

Comment: I will try. Also. How do we display left and over ? Like 2 minutes left or 5 minutes over. ? Please include entire codes as function as part of ur answer :)

Comment: I'm not really used to do this kind of stuff, but it should easy to just check the difference between 2 dates by converting them into timestamps and if it's positive its "left" and negative its "over"